# error 400 bad request in codeignitier

Tags: codeigniter

need help this my code javascript

```
function edit_kamar(Kode)
    {
    save_method = 'update';
    $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
    $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string
    //Ajax Load data from ajax
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('kamar_view/ajax_edit')?>/"+Kode,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('[name="Kode"]').val(data.Kode);
            $('[name="Deskripsi"]').val(data.Deskripsi);
            $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
            $('.modal-title').text('FORM EDIT KAMAR'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

            $('#Gambar-preview').show(); // show Gambar preview modal

            if(data.Gambar)
            {
                $('#label-Gambar').text('GANTI GAMBAR'); // label Gambar upload
                $('#Gambar-preview div').html('<img src="'+base_url+'upload/'+data.Gambar+'" class="img-responsive">'); // show Gambar
               // $('#Gambar-preview div').append('<input type="checkbox" name="remove_Gambar" value="'+data.Gambar+'"/> Remove Gambar when saving'); // remove Gambar

            }
            else
            {
                $('#label-Gambar').text('UPLOAD GAMBAR'); // label Gambar upload
                $('#Gambar-preview div').text('(No Gambar)');
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error get data from ajax');
        }
    });
    }
```

this my view code

```
<section class="content">
    <!-- List View box -->
    <div class="box xlist-view">
    <div class="box-body table-scroll">     

   <!--    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="reload_table()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Refresh</button>   -->
                <br><br>
            <table id="table_id" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
          <tr>

            <th style="width:1px; font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;NO</FONT></th>  
            <th style="width:1px; font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;" style="font-size:10px" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;KODE</FONT></th>
            <th style="width:1px; font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;" style="font-size:10px" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;RUANGAN</FONT></th>
            <th style="width:1px; font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;" style="font-size:10px" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;KELAS</FONT></th>
            <th style="width:1px; font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;" style="font-size:10px" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;KAMAR</FONT></th>
            <th style="width:100px; font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;" style="font-size:10px" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">JUMLAH TT</FONT></th>
            <th style="width:100px; font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;" style="font-size:10px" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">SISA TT</FONT></th>
            <th style="width:1px; font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;" style="font-size:10px" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;TARIF</FONT></th>
            <th style="width:100px; font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;" style="font-size:10px" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">DESK</FONT></th>
            <th style="width:100px; font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;" style="font-size:10px" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;IMAGE</FONT></th>
            <th style="width:100px; font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;" style="font-size:10px" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KONTROL</FONT></center> </th>
          </tr>
          </thead>                  
            <tbody> 
            <?php 
                $no = 0;
                foreach($displaykamar as $book)
                {
                $no++;
                ?>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;"><center><?php echo $no;?></td>
                        <td style="font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;"><center><?php echo $book->Kode;?></td>
                        <td style="font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle; "><center><?php echo $book->Ruangan;?></td>
                        <td style="font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;"><center><?php echo $book->Kelas;?></td>
                        <td style="font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;"><center><?php echo $book->Kamar;?></td>
                        <td style="font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;"><center><?php echo $book->JumlahTT;?></td>
                        <td style="font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;"><center><?php echo $book->SisaTT;?></td>
                        <td style="font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;"><center><?php echo number_format($book->Tarif,2,",",".")?></center></td>
                        <td style="font-size:12px; vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $book->Deskripsi;?></td>
                            <?php 
                                if($book->Gambar)           
                                //  echo '<td width="10%"><center><img src="base_url('upload/'.$book->Gambar)" class="img-responsive" width="85px" height="85px" /></a></center></td>';
                                    echo '<td width="10%"><center><img src="'.base_url('upload/'.$book->Gambar).'" class="img-responsive" width="85px" height="85px"></center></td>';
                                else
                                    echo '<td width="10%"><center><img src="'.base_url('upload/noimage_kamar.png').'" class="img-responsive" width="75px" height="75px"></center></td>';
                                //  echo '<td width="10%"><center><img src="upload/noimage_kamar.png" class="img-responsive" width="75px" height="75px" /></center></td>';
                                ?>

                                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><center>
                                    <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="edit_kamar(<?php echo $book->Kode;?>)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
<!--                                <button class="btn btn-warning" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit_kamar(<?php echo $book->Kode;?>)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_book(<?php echo $book->Kode;?>)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>  -->

                                </td>
                      </tr>
                     <?php }?>          
            </tbody>

            <tfoot>            
            </tfoot>                                
                </table>

            <!--    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="reload_table()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Refresh</button>   -->
      </div>      

    </div>
```

this is the error:

```
localhost:8080/Simrsgum1/kamar_view/ajax_edit/2.16100001161e+24
```

## An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

[image]

cause i think the link should get all of number not get cut
should like this maybe :

```
localhost:8080/Simrsgum1/kamar_view/ajax_edit/2161000011610000116100001
```

Comment: what about your controller's code..can you post?

Comment: pass the parameter in encode state just encode it to base64 and then decode it.

Comment: @Hikmat Sijapati if manual edit header and resend yes its show
@ Yaseen Ahmed need sample code

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS CODE.**

Please open your config.php file and then find this

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-';
```

And then you need to set the value to blank

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '';
```

And after that try again and your script working fine.

Comment: hi Shailesh Prajapati thats for some security reason not allowed to using blank ' ';

Comment: You can try this $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-+'; add plus sign at the end of the string.